# Google script Type error when try to move files to folder

Tags: file, google-apps-script, directory, move

I'm trying to select multiple files depending on the mime type (JPG and Google Docs in this example) and move to specific folders for each type. So I tried the following:

```
function test() {
  var srcfolderId = "abcdefghi"; 

  var jpgFolderID=DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).createFolder("jpgfiles").getId();
  var gdocFolderID=DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).createFolder("gdocfiles").getId();

  var jpgfiles=DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  var gdocfiles=DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);

  jpgfiles.moveTo(jpgFolderID);
  gdocfiles.moveTo(gdocFolderID);
}
```

But this creates the error:

```
TypeError: jpgfiles.moveTo is not a function
```

What should I need to do to escape from this error? Should I use a different way to move multiple files to a specific folder?

Comment: jpgfiles is an iterator not a file [see this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getFilesByType(String))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The reason for your issue of `TypeError: jpgfiles.moveTo is not a function` is due to that the argument of `moveTo` is the folder object. In your script, the folder ID is used.
- `DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId)` can be declared as one variable.
- `getFilesByType` returns FileIterator.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function test() {
  var srcfolderId = "abcdefghi";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcfolderId);
  var jpgFolder = folder.createFolder("jpgfiles");
  var gdocFolder = folder.createFolder("gdocfiles");
 
  var jpgfiles = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  while (jpgfiles.hasNext()) {
    jpgfiles.next().moveTo(jpgFolder);
  }

  var gdocfiles = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (gdocfiles.hasNext()) {
    gdocfiles.next().moveTo(gdocFolder);
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getFilesByType(mimeType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbytypemimetype)
- [moveTo(destination)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#movetodestination)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like this:

```
while(jpgfiles.hasNext()) {
  let file = jpgfiles.next();
  file.mmoveTo()....
```